# How to update all rows for a column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update multiple rows on one column (SQL Server 2008). The column I need to update has insert and update trigger. When I run this script I got an error message:

```
 UPDATE htable
    SET Isverified=1
  WHERE columnname IN ('122','566','652')
```

Error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure mydatabasename, Line 22
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I don't know how true this is but I want to believe due to the trigger define on this column. Did any want know how I can achieve this
 here is the trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[sendTodbase]
ON  [dbo].[htable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
SET NOCOUNT ON
--CHECK IF DATAENTRY COLUMN IS UPDATED
IF UPDATE(Isverified) begin
declare @dEVer bit declare @rcNum varchar(50) 
declare @idenNum varchar(50) declare @docId bigint

--GET INSERTED VALUE AND CHECK IF IT's (YES) THEN CONTINUE...
select @dEVer = (select Isverified from inserted i)
if @dEVer = 1 begin
--END CHECK, IF DE IS COMPLETED CONTINUE----

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: You are missing a `set` clause (which would specify which column you want to change and to which value)

Comment: Also your error message doesnt refer to the query you posted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have posted the complete error message

Comment: The `update` statement you posted is invalid. It will generate a completely different error. So I guess you didn't show us the real `update` statement. Check the triggers, the error message you posted probably means that your triggers can't handle more than one affected row

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i have pasted the complete error message. Note, the database name mydatabasename is where records are sent to from the main database where am doing the update

Comment: Can you post the code for the underlying trigger?

Comment: First of all - the trigger is **on the table** - you cannot have a trigger on a single column. And secondly: the trigger is most likely the cause of the trouble - so please **post the code** for the trigger!

Comment: @marc_s , i have posted my part of my trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is probably generated by:

```
select @dEVer = (select Isverified from inserted i)
```

TSQL interpreter expects no more than one row returned by `select Isverified from inserted i` subquery.

Your `update` query affets more than one row and exception `Subquery returned more than 1 value` is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
Update mydatble set ColumnName = <Require value>
where columnname in ('122','566','652')
```